# PyQt5 : how can I get the content of a QTextEdit to refresh on tab change?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

[Question reformulated for clarity]

I have a simple GUI with 2 tabs, the first one contains a read only QTextEdit used for program logs, the second one contains various widgets for user input and a "generate" button.

The GUI was made using Qt Designer. Note : all elements have default attributes ( they were not edited / no options changed ) apart from the QTextEdit that is read only
The arrows are to show the QTextEdit that is used for the logs and the generate button that causes the tab change

[image]

Upon clicking on the generate button, the focused tab is switched to the first one ( with the logs ) and a separate thread is used to compute the user data and write it's log onto the QTextEdit

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, core):
        self.core = core
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = Application()
        self.__link_buttons__()

    def __link_buttons__(self):
        generate_button = self.window.get_generate_button()
        if generate_button is None:
            raise RuntimeError("could not find the generation button needed for the gui ( possibly an issue with the .gui file ), cannot start software")
        generate_button.clicked.connect(self.__generate_threaded)

    def __generate_threaded(self):
        logger.logger_instance.log("user requested generation", LogLevel.NORMAL)
        self.window.set_main_tab_to_log()
        if self.core.check_if_generating() is True:
        logger.logger_instance.log("Generator is currently in use", LogLevel.ERROR)
            return
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.core.generate_gui)
        thread.start()

class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(settings.settings_instance.gui_path / "main_window.ui", self)
        self.show()
        self.__tabs = self.ui.findChild(QTabWidget, "mainTabs")
        self.__log_tab = self.ui.findChild(QWidget, "logTab")

    def get_gui_handle(self):
        return self.ui.findChild(QTextEdit, "LogOutput")

    def get_generate_button(self):
        return self.ui.findChild(QPushButton, "generateButton")

    def set_main_tab_to_log(self):
        self.__tabs.setCurrentWidget(self.__log_tab)
```

The logger is the class that is in charge of writing to the QTextEdit on the GUI, it calls the `get_gui_handle()` method on start to get the QTextEdit and then uses `append()` to write to it ( with thread protection )

Possibly important details : I am using the standard Python threads ( `import threading` ), not the Qt as the rest of the software uses them and I am unsure if they can be mixed

The logger does write successfully to the QTextEdit but the application does not display the text as intended. Any new text is displayed normally but the previous logs are not and will only show upon window resize / clicking on the text / changing tabs / ... ( what I presume are events that get the application to re-render the QTextEdit )

Pictures for clarity :

First log is displayed as intended :

[image]

Second log is also displayed as intended but the first log is now invisible

[image]

First log is displayed again after window resize / text overlining / tab change

[image]

Comment: Besides the above suggestion about a MRE, I ask you to consider this: you've given us details, but they're not *actual* details. For instance: "a QTextEdit that I use for logging": logging of *what*? and *how* is it done? "the output is generated": generated *how*? and from *what*? From what you're trying to explain, the first idea is that you're probably trying to use threading in some way (which does **not** allow direct access to UI elements, hence the update issues - and you're lucky, as that often results in fatal crash), but we cannot be sure until your details become *actual* details.

Comment: sorry about that, I will edit the question, it is indeed not clear enough

Comment: Added a lot more context and code, thank you for the guidance ^^

Comment: Now it's better, but still insufficient. As suspected, you're using threads, and that's most certainly the source of the issue (the UI should *always* be in the main thread, and absolutely **no direct access** should be attempted to UI elements from external threads), but we cannot tell anything more unless you provide a *complete* [mre]: your code is missing *very* important parts, such as `generate_gui` and what actually tries to update the text; please consider that we should be able to copy, paste and run your code without any substantial modification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a bit hard to do as the code is very big, I think it will be simpler if I create a small example from scratch rather than trying to extract the important parts ( the code is thousands of lines long ). The UI is run from the main thread and any heavy computing is done on separate threads. You seem to suspect something about the threads, how should I handle writing from a separate thread to the QTextEdit ? Is there an event / method I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that even though I was using thread protections, ***I was calling the `append()` method from a separate thread*** ( thread protection is not enough ! ). Trying to refresh / actualize the gui after a call from a different thread is also a bad idea.
This is due to the fact that Qt manages internally events and that not using the main thread seems to circumvent them with in turn causes Qt to not see that it's content was changed.

**Important** note for the solution : using threads or qt threads is irrelevant in this specific case as qt simply wraps a threading library. It is however **very** recommended to use qt threads on all of the software simply to avoid having 2 different threads library used in the same program, witch in turn can cause issues.

I used `pyqtSignal` in order to be able to correctly communicate with the gui without having issues

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class GUI(QObject):
    __gui_log_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init___():
        # ...
        self.__gui_handle = self.window.get_gui_handle() # this method returns the reference to the QTextEdit directly
        self.__gui_log_signal.connect(self.__gui_handle.append)
```

This way I can use `self.__gui_log_signal.emit("string or variable here")` when needed

Important details to note : ( things that made getting the answer in the first place harder than expected )

- The `pyqtSygnal` must be at the root of the class, not in the `__init__()` else it's not going to work properly ( in my instance the `emit()` method was not found )
- the `pyqtSignal` can be used to pass variables, they just need to be declared as such ( example : `pqtSygnal(str)` ) and then connected to a method that uses the same types / variable count
- The class that uses the `pyqtSygnal` must extend `QObject` or a class that extends it